# Configure SQL Server Job with dtsx

Tags: ssis, sql-job, sql-server-2019

I migrated from SQL Server 2008 to 2019. On the old server there is set up a job, which calls a `dtsx` file. It needs database access, file system access because it saves tmp files to disk, and internet conneciton to send this file.
The connection string is defined followings:

```
<DTS:ConnectionManager
      DTS:ConnectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=p@ssword;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MyUser;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Data Source=SQLServer\Instance;" />
```

If I run it using the `Execute Package Utility` it works. If I run it through the SQLServer Job, I get the error that the user is not granted to access the file system. The owner of the job is the same I am logged in and run the package using the Utility.

In the history i see:

```
The job failed.  The Job was invoked by User Domain\RightUser.....
```

where RightUser is the Owner (and same as before, the same user run the package using the utility)

but the second row of the error:

```
Executed as user: NT Service\SQLAgent$AnotherUser.
```

And I have no idea where this AnotherUser comes from.

Whats wrong?

Furthermore, I don't really like the hardcoded password in the connection string, If the job run in its owner context, should it work changing the connection string to `Integrated Security=True;`, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem with running SSIS packages. That other user is SQL Agent, which in reality runs the package (this is the default user running the steps in jobs). Job owner has got nothing to do with running the SSIS packages. SQL Agent user name is set during the SQL Server installation. If it's omitted, the installer creates automatically a username like you described.

To the second question, yes you are right. If the user, who executes the package, has the correct permissions to the SQL Server described in the connection string, the userid and password are unnecessary. But in your case, the package is run by the SQL Agent with NT Service -level username, so it might be impossible to add that username to the SQL Server. You should set up a proper username for running the SSIS package and set it as a proxy account to the SQL Server, like described here: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/129293-configure-an-ssis-package-to-execute-as-a-proxy-account